# Flipper: Connection Error on fresh install on Mac

Tags: react-native, flipper, fbflipper

Getting the following error on a fresh install of Flipper on Mac:

```
Connection error
Couldn't start connection server. Looks like you have multiple copies of Flipper running or another process is using the same port(s). As a result devices will not be able to connect to Flipper.

Please try to kill the offending process by running kill $(lsof -ti:PORTNUMBER) and restart flipper.

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8089
```

But when I kill the process on 8089, it just starts up again.

### Mac Version

OS: macOS Monterey v12.6.3
chip: Apple M1

### Custom Port

I tried setting up Flipper to use a custom port by following the instructions at: https://fbflipper.com/docs/custom-ports/, but this didn't help.

I ran the following command but it didn't help:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted defaults write "Apple Global Domain" "com.facebook.flipper.ports" -string "1111,2222"
```

Flipper doctor says that everything is ok.

Also, despite the fact that I'm running a react native app in Xcode simulator, I get the following warning in the flipper app:

```
NO DEVICES FOUND No devices found Start a fresh emulator  or check the troubleshooting guide.
```

But when I click on the "Start Emulator / Simulator" icon in Flipper, it opens a modal and nothing happens. A spinner comes up and spins infinitely.

Any advice?